# How to implement property() with dynamic name (in python)

Tags: python, oop, parameters, properties

I am programming a simulations for single neurons. Therefore I have to handle a lot of Parameters. Now the Idea is that I have two classes, one for a SingleParameter and a Collection of parameters. I use property() to access the parameter value easy and to make the code more readable. This works perfect for a sinlge parameter but I don't know how to implement it for the collection as I want to name the property in Collection after the SingleParameter. Here an example:

```
class SingleParameter(object):
  def __init__(self, name, default_value=0, unit='not specified'):
    self.name = name
    self.default_value = default_value
    self.unit = unit
    self.set(default_value)
  def get(self):
    return self._v
  def set(self, value):
    self._v = value
  v = property(fget=get, fset=set, doc='value of parameter')

par1 = SingleParameter(name='par1', default_value=10, unit='mV')
par2 = SingleParameter(name='par2', default_value=20, unit='mA')

# par1 and par2 I can access perfectly via 'p1.v = ...'
# or get its value with 'p1.v'

class Collection(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.dict = {}
  def __getitem__(self, name):
    return self.dict[name] # get the whole object
    # to get the value instead:
    # return self.dict[name].v
  def add(self, parameter):
    self.dict[parameter.name] = parameter
    # now comes the part that I don't know how to implement with property():
    # It shoule be something like
    # self.__dict__[parameter.name] = property(...) ?

col = Collection()
col.add(par1)
col.add(par2)
col['par1'] # gives the whole object

# Now here is what I would like to get:
# col.par1 -> should result like col['par1'].v
# col.par1 = 5 -> should result like col['par1'].v = 5
```

---

Other questions that I put to understand property():

- [Why do managed attributes just work for class attributes and not for instance attributes in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428264)
- [How can I assign a new class attribute via __dict__ in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432786/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the same get/set functions for both classes forces you into an ugly hack with the argument list. Very sketchy, this is how I would do it:

In class SingleParameter, define get and set as usual:

```
def get(self):
  return self._s
def set(self, value):
  self._s = value
```

In class Collection, you cannot know the information until you create the property, so you define the metaset/metaget function and particularize them only later with a lambda function:

```
def metaget(self, par):
  return par.s
def metaset(self, value, par):
  par.s = value
def add(self, par):
  self[par.name] = par
  setattr(Collection, par.name,
    property(
      fget=lambda x : Collection.metaget(x, par),
      fset=lambda x, y : Collection.metaset(x,y, par))
```

Answer (score 10):

Look at built-in functions `getattr` and `setattr`.  You'll probably be a lot happier.

Answer (score 5):

Properties are meant to dynamically evaluate attributes or to make them read-only. What you need is customizing attribute access. `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` do that really fine, and there's also `__getattribute__` if `__getattr__` is not enough.

See [Python docs on customizing attribute access](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) for details.

Comment: when I add:
-----
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
  self.dict[name] = value
----
I get the error message that " 'Collection' object has no attribute 'dict' " - although it is implemented in __init__.

Comment: ok, I implemented it now with set-/getattr. see answer below!

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [traits package](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/)? It seems that you are reinventing the wheel here with your parameter classes. Traits also have additional features that might be useful for your type of application (incidently I know a person that happily uses traits in neural simulations).

Comment: Thanks alot. I came across traits once but didn't really get what they are good for. Probably now is the right time to have another look :-) !

Answer (score 2):

Now I implemented a solution with set-/getattr:

```
class Collection(object):
...
  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if 'dict' in self.__dict__:
      if name in self.dict:
        self[name].v = value
    else:
      self.__dict__[name] = value
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return self[name].v
```

There is one thing I quite don't like that much: The attributes are not in the __dict__. And if I have them there as well I would have a copy of the value - which can be dangerous...

Comment: well, then just don't put a copy of them there. It would be hard to do anyway since you've overrided setattr.

Comment: It's not recommended to use built-in type names for variables. Consider changing the 'dict' attribute name to something more self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I succeded to implement the classes with property(). Thanks a lot for the advice. It took me quite a bit to work it out - but I can promise you that this exercise helps you to understand better pythons OOP.

I implemented it also with __getattr__ and __setattr__ but still don't know the advantages and disadvantages to the property-solution. But this seems to be worth another question. The property-solutions seems to be quit clean.

So here is the code:

```
class SingleParameter(object):
  def __init__(self, name, default_value=0, unit='not specified'):
    self.name = name
    self.default_value = default_value
    self.unit = unit
    self.set(default_value)
  def get(*args):
    self = args[0]
    print "get(): "
    print args
    return self._v
  def set(*args):
    print "set(): "
    print args
    self = args[0]
    value = args[-1]
    self._v = value
  v = property(fget=get, fset=set, doc='value of parameter')

class Collection(dict):
  # inheriting from dict saves the methods: __getitem__ and __init__
  def add(self, par):
    self[par.name] = par
    # Now here comes the tricky part.
    # (Note: this property call the get() and set() methods with one
    # more argument than the property of SingleParameter)
    setattr(Collection, par.name,
      property(fget=par.get, fset=par.set))

# Applying the classes:
par1 = SingleParameter(name='par1', default_value=10, unit='mV')
par2 = SingleParameter(name='par2', default_value=20, unit='mA')
col = Collection()
col.add(par1)
col.add(par2)
# Setting parameter values:
par1.v = 13
col.par1 = 14
# Getting parameter values:
par1.v
col.par1
# checking identity:
par1.v is col.par1
# to access the whole object:
col['par1']
```

As I am new I am not sure how to move on:
how to treat follow up questions (like this itself):

- get() is seems to be called twice - why?
- oop-design: property vs. "__getattr__ & __setattr__" - when should I use what?
- is it rude to check the own answer to the own question as *accepted*?
- is it recommended to rename the title in order to put correlated questions or questions elaborated with the same example into the same context?

Other questions that I put to understand property():

- [Why do managed attributes just work for class attributes and not for instance attributes in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428264)
- [How can I assign a new class attribute via __dict__ in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432786/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a class that does something similar, but I did the following in the collection object:

setattr(self, par.name, par.v)