# Why do managed attributes just work for class attributes and not for instance attributes in python?

Tags: python, attributes, descriptor

To illustrate the question check the following code:

```
class MyDescriptor(object):
  def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
    print "get", self, obj, type
    return self._v
  def __set__(self, obj, value):
    self._v = value
    print "set", self, obj, value
    return None

class SomeClass1(object):
  m = MyDescriptor()

class SomeClass2(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.m = MyDescriptor()

x1 = SomeClass1()
x2 = SomeClass2()

x1.m = 1000
# ->  set <__main__.MyDescriptor object at 0xb787c7ec> <__main__.SomeClass1 object at 0xb787cc8c> 10000
x2.m = 1000 # I guess that this overwrites the function. But why?
# ->
print x1.m
# -> get <__main__.MyDescriptor object at 0xb787c7ec> <__main__.SomeClass1 object at 0xb787cc8c> <class '__main__.SomeClass1'> 10000
print x2.m
# -> 10000
```

1. Why doesn't **x2.m = 1000** not call the **__set__**-function? It seems that this overwrites the function. But why?
2. Where is **_v** in x1? It is not in **x1._v**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your second question, where is `_v`?

Your version of the descriptor keeps `_v` in the descriptor itself.   Each instance of the descriptor (the class-level instance `SomeClass1`, and all of the object-level instances in objects of class `SomeClass2` will have distinct values of `_v`.

Look at this version.  This version updates the object associated with the descriptor.  This means the object (`SomeClass1` or `x2`) will contain the attribute `_v`.

```
class MyDescriptor(object):
  def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
    print "get", self, obj, type
    return obj._v
  def __set__(self, obj, value):
    obj._v = value
    print "set", self, obj, value
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea to implement. One question to _v: I also couldn't access it via "MyDescriptor._v" - which is clear as it not a class attribute of MyDescriptor. But what is the explicit name of the instance? It should be accessible somehow, right?

Comment: You cannot access it, because it gets overwritten. In S.Lott case, you can access it via x._v

Comment: Descriptor instances are HARD to access -- the point is that the containing class transparently calls their __set__ and __get__ functions for you.  It never refers to the descriptor -- it calls the __set__ or __get__.

Comment: @Sebastjan Trepča: it's better to completely fix a comment by posting a new one and deleting the old comment.  A sequence of comments is hard to read.  But a new, complete comment is better.

Answer (score 3):

You should read [this](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) and [this](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm).

It overwrites the function because you didn't overload the `__set__` and `__get__` functions of SomeClass but of MyDescriptor class. Maybe you wanted for SomeClass to inherit MyDescriptor? SomeClass1 prints the "get" and "set" output because it's a static method AFAIK. For details read the upper links.

Answer (score 0):

I found **_v** of **x1**: It is in **SomeClass1.__dict__['m']._v**

For the version suggested by S.Lott within the other answer: **_v** is in **x1._v**