# How to assign a new class attribute via __dict__?

Tags: python, oop, class, attributes

I want to assign a class attribute via a string object - but how?

Example:

```
class test(object):
  pass

a = test()
test.value = 5
a.value
# -> 5
test.__dict__['value']
# -> 5

# BUT:
attr_name = 'next_value'

test.__dict__[attr_name] = 10
# -> 'dictproxy' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There is a builtin function for this:

```
setattr(test, attr_name, 10)
```

Reference: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr

Example:

```
>>> class a(object): pass
>>> a.__dict__['wut'] = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dictproxy' object does not support item assignment
>>> setattr(a, 'wut', 7)
>>> a.wut
7
```

Comment: This seems to work for me from inside the object: self.__dict__.update(result) where result is a dict

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56450631/1626431) answer "a mappingproxy is simply a dict with no __setattr__ method."