# Assign array to key dictionary in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary, sdk

I'm not guru in python. I don't get why I can't assign an array of values to a key for this dictionnary with this def.

This is how I use the sdk definition.

```
order_obj = Order(None)
order_obj.customerIp("14.140.42.67")
order_obj.merchantRefNum(RandomTokenGenerator().generateToken())
order_obj.currencyCode("CAD")
order_obj.totalAmount("1125")

redirect = Redirect(None)
redirect.rel("on_success")
redirect.uri("http://outwander.ca:{}/redirect")
return_keys_list = []
return_keys_list.append('id')
return_keys_list.append('transaction.amount')
redirect.returnKeys(return_keys_list)
redirect_list = []
redirect_list.append(redirect.__dict__)
order_obj.redirect(redirect_list)
```

This is the specific definition in the sdk I use
https://github.com/OptimalPayments/Python_SDK/blob/63e1ae662a4447bd65c907563eec9effc602dd74/src/PythonNetBanxSDK/HostedPayment/Redirect.py

```
'''
Property Return Keys
'''   
def returnKeys(self, return_keys):
    self.__dict__['returnKeys'] = return_keys
```

**From what I could debug, the problems comes when converting the array into json to be sent.The loop finds the array and try to convert the elements inside (strings), but since by default the loop consider each given parameter as array, the returnKeys parameter is skipped...**

```
'''
Serializing object
@param: Dictionary Object
@return: Serialized data
'''
def serialize(self, obj):
    return (json.dumps(self.to_dictionary(obj)))

'''
Convert object to a dictionary
@param: POJO Object
@return: Dictionary Object
'''
def to_dictionary(self, obj):
    obj_dict = dict()
    for key in obj.__dict__.keys():
        try:
            if(type(obj.__dict__[key]) is list):
                content = []
                for count in range(0, obj.__dict__[key].__len__()):
                    content.append(
                            self.to_dictionary(obj.__dict__[key][count]))
                obj_dict[key] = content
            elif(isinstance(obj.__dict__[key], DomainObject)):
                obj_dict[key] = self.to_dictionary(obj.__dict__[key])
            else:
                obj_dict[key] = obj.__dict__[key]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    return (obj_dict)
```

I have no problem assigning a key to one value, but when I try assigning an array to a key, it doesn't work and it just ignore this key from the json output.

SOLUTION (HACK)

```
order_obj = Order(None)
order_obj.customerIp("14.140.42.67")
order_obj.merchantRefNum(RandomTokenGenerator().generateToken())
order_obj.currencyCode("CAD")
order_obj.totalAmount("1125")

redirect = Redirect(None)
redirect.rel("on_success")
redirect.uri("http://outwander.ca:{}/redirect")
redirect.returnKeys(('id', 'transaction.amount'))
redirect_list = []
redirect_list.append(redirect.__dict__)
order_obj.redirect((redirect_list))
```

Comment: So the problem is in some other code that you haven't included in the question?

Comment: *the code throw an exception* - which code, and what exception?  You should use `setattr()` in preference to `__dict__`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432786/how-can-i-assign-a-new-class-attribute-via-dict-in-python

Comment: @khelwood Included all I know. I'm not familiar with the SDK, but it's open source.

Comment: Please include the exception you are getting

Comment: I'm not getting any exception. It's just that I don't get the expected json string. Instead it's empty. I tried on a python compiler online to assign values to a key with a dict and it works... So my guess it's in the serialization. You might want to look in the to_dictionary definition... @rrauenza

Comment: Ok, I've reproduced this -- running through the debugger.

Comment: @rrauenza I believe the error reside in the serialization from the SDK. `for count in range(0, obj.__dict__[key].__len__()):
                    content.append(
                            self.to_dictionary(obj.__dict__[key][count]))
                obj_dict[key] = content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced this:

```
import json

class S:

    def serialize(self, obj):
        return (json.dumps(self.to_dictionary(obj)))

    def to_dictionary(self, obj):
        obj_dict = dict()
        for key in obj.__dict__.keys():
            try:
                if(type(obj.__dict__[key]) is list):
                    content = []
                    for count in range(0, obj.__dict__[key].__len__()):
                        content.append(self.to_dictionary(obj.__dict__[key][count]))
                    obj_dict[key] = content
                # elif(isinstance(obj.__dict__[key], DomainObject)):
                #    obj_dict[key] = self.to_dictionary(obj.__dict__[key])
                else:
                    obj_dict[key] = obj.__dict__[key]
            except KeyError:
                pass
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        return (obj_dict)


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "1234"                                                         
        self.b = (1, 2, 3, 4)                                                   
        self.c = [1, 2, 3, 4]                                                   
        self.d = { 1: 2, 3: 4}               

print S().serialize(A())
```

Output:

```
{"a": "1234", "b": [1, 2, 3, 4], "d": {"1": 2, "3": 4}}
```

The problem is that when the code recurses into `to_dictionary()` with the items in the list, the code always expects that it is recursing with a object that contains a `__dict__`.  But neither a string (nor an int) contain a `__dict__`.  (Which I see you've stated similarly in the question.)

I would file an issue on the github referring to this question.

Other than patching their code, your only option is to create a class that has the items you want.  It appears they do not support a `string` or `int` except as a value in a `__dict__`.

You could use a `dict` as a list:

```
class ReturnList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = { 1: "Item1", 2: "Item2" }

redirect.returnKeys(ReturnList())
```

Addendum:

Wait!  Why did the tuple case work??  I think you could do:

```
redirect.returnKeys((1,2,3,4))
```

Oh, I see why it works.  It's a bug.  They specifically handle `list` but not `tuple`, and it doesn't recurse for `tuple` types.  Since the `tuple` contains directly `json`-able types, it just converts it to a `json` list.  If your `tuple` contained a class or other more complex (non-`json`) objects, it would fail.

If you want to patch their code locally, or ask them to patch their code, it could be modified like this to both accept tuples and to properly handle `int` and `string`:

```
if(isinstance(obj.__dict__[key], (list, tuple)):
    for count in range(0, obj.__dict__[key].__len__()):
        item = obj.__dict__[key][count])
        if not isinstance(item, (str, int)):
            item = self.to_dictionary(obj.__dict__[key][count])
        content.append(item)
```

For maintainability (in case you ever get a new version of their SDK), I'd probably figure out a way to use a `dict` instead of a `list` and just make the indexes into your `dict` be integers, similar to a `list`.  i.e., `foo = { 0: 'string1', 1: 'string2', 2: 'string3', }; redirect.returnKeys(foo)`

A quick way to convert your `list` into a `dict` is with

```
l = ['string1', 'string2', ]
dictified_list = dict(zip(l, range(0, len(l))))
redirect.returnkeys(dictified_list)
```

Comment: I don't want my list to be a key. I want multiple values for one key.self.__dict__['returnKeys'] = return_keys where return_keys = an array of values

Comment: edited... but I'm going to need to look at the SDK you're using to better understand your problem.  Can you include your error messages in the question?

Comment: How can I fix this recursive definition to handle strings?

Comment: Put them in a tuple.  Until their SDK breaks that.  Or put them in a dict that you use as a list.  My examples used numbers, but strings work fine, too.

Comment: By fix do you mean fix the underlying SDK code?  Or workaround by changing what you pass?

Comment: I actually imported the local SDK and want to change the code to make strings array works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114152/discussion-between-fneron-and-rrauenza).