# Define a class that stores all the informations about an element from multiple lists

Tags: python, list, class

I have the following item lists:

```
planets = ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Uranus', 'Neptune', 'Pluto']
sunDist = [57.9, 108.2, 149.6, 227.9, 778.3, 1427, 2870, 4497, 5900]
revolut = [88, 224.7, 365.2, 687, 4328, 10752, 651160, 1020707, 1338090]
satsNum = [0, 0, 1, 2, 63, 56, 27, 13, 3]
dlabels = ['Planet', 'Distance from the Sun', 'Duration of the year', 'Number of satellites']
```

**Exercise 1.**
Print a list of planets sorted according to their number of satellites (from low to high).
(Provide the solution writing your own sorting method (e.g. Bubble Sort))

My solution:

```
satsforplanet = list(zip(satsNum, planets))

def bubble(list_a):
    indexing_length = len(list_a) - 1
    sorted = False

    while not sorted:
        sorted = True
        for i in range(0, indexing_length):
            if list_a[i][0] > list_a[i+1][0]:
                sorted = False
                list_a[i], list_a[i+1] = list_a[i+1], list_a[i]

    sortedlist = []
    for element in list_a:
        sortedlist.append(element[1])
    return sortedlist
```

**Exercise 2.**
Write a function planetData(pName) that takes the name of a planet and returns a dictionary with all the data for that planet, where the keys are the labels in dlabels and the values the relevant data.

My solution:

```
def planetData(pName):

    zipped = list(zip(planets, sunDist, revolut, satsNum))

    dic = {}
    for i in range(len(planets)):
        nameplanet = planets[i]
        dic[nameplanet] = {}
        j = 0
        for key in dlabels:
            dic[nameplanet][key] = zipped[i][j]
            j += 1
    
    if pName in dic:
        return dic[pName]
    else:
        return 'Write the right name of the planet'
```

**Exercise 3**
Define a class Planet that stores all the information about a planet. Adapt the code you wrote for Exercises 1 and 2 to this new type. Further, define a method of the Planet class that takes as input a number of days and returns to how many years they correspond for the specific planet.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve the third exercise? I have no idea where to start.

I know that for each planet I have to store all information relating to the planet and be able to recall all the information I need, but I'm not sure how the exercise would like me to do it.

I thought I had to define the `Planet` class starting from the names of the planets, giving each planet the attributes contained in the `dlabels` list.

I think the result should be, for example, that if I write
`print(Pluto)`, the output should be a dictionary like the output in the second exercise:

```
{'Planet': 'Pluto',
 'Distance from the Sun': 5900,
 'Duration of the year': 1338090,
 'Number of satellites': 3}
```

Instead, if I write `Pluto.name`, the output should be `'Pluto'`, if I write `Pluto.satellites` the output should be `0` and so on.

The problem is that I have no idea how to iterate this procedure for all the planets, anyone can help me, please?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432786/how-to-assign-a-new-class-attribute-via-dict